# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Just now I was getting this error when running a stored procedure:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
```

I located the line where that error was coming from and this is the code on that line:

```
SELECT @AF_MIN_3L = LEFT(MIN([A-F Est_CY]), 6) - 0.000001 FROM #Ent_AF_3
```

Earlier in the stored procedure, I declared @AF_MIN_3L as data type FLOAT, created the temp table #Ent_AF_3 and in doing so, made the column [A-F Est_CY] data type FLOAT. Is the following code creating a non-FLOAT value?

```
LEFT(MIN([A-F Est_CY]), 6) - 0.000001
```

I hope it's a simple casting issue and all I have to do is something like this:

```
LEFT(MIN(CAST([A-F Est_CY] AS FLOAT)), 6) - CAST(0.000001 AS FLOAT)
```

I didn't want to run the whole procedure again without being sure I fixed the issue. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you need to cast it back to float before the subtraction: `SELECT @AF_MIN_3L = CAST(LEFT(MIN([A-F Est_CY]), 6) AS float ) - 0.000001 FROM #Ent_AF_3` but I guess it depends on what it is you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: It seems like your operations are out of order - shouldn't that be `MIN(CAST(LEFT([A-F Est_CY], 6) AS FLOAT))`?  Take the left 6 characters, convert to float, and find the minimum?

Comment: What's your goal e.g. `select @a=-0.00001` leads to `select @a` > `-1E-05`  and `select LEFT(@a, 6)` > `-1e-00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a string function, which is what `LEFT` is, it resturns a string value. As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx), the return datatype of the `LEFT` function does indeed return a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`. So, ideed, a `CAST` or `CONVERT` back to `FLOAT` is required. You should of course convert back to `FLOAT` AFTER the `LEFT` function, so it would be: CAST(LEFT(...) as FLOAT).

Comment: This worked great, thanks. `CAST(LEFT(MIN([A-F Est_CY]), 6) AS FLOAT) - 0.000001` erased the error.

Comment: @ultimate8 `Declare @a float
select @a=-0.00001
select CAST(LEFT(@a, 6) AS FLOAT) - 0.000001` will lead to `-1,000001` , I don't think this is what you would like to get?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your precision - if you have a float > 0.999999 on the temp file you will get the error because of the implicit conversion.

Use:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(MIN([A-F Est_CY]), 6) AS float) - 0.000001 FROM #Ent_AF_4
```

Comment: Didn't see this until after I re-ran my procedure but this is exactly what I ended up doing. It ran error free so thank you.